# Fixture not found while running a test (DDT Pytest)

Tags: python, csv, testing, automated-tests, pytest

I've met an error "fixture 'invalid_email'" not found, while running this test:

```
import pytest
import time

from ddt import ddt, data, unpack
from pages.home.signup_page import SignUpPage
from utilities.read_data import get_csv_data


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("base_set_up", "set_up")
@ddt
class TestSignUp():

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def class_set_up(self, base_set_up):
        self.test_user = SignUpPage(self.driver)

    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_valid_sign_up_with_confirmation(self):
        self.test_user.valid_signup()
        self.test_user.use_mailer()
        result = self.test_user.verify_successful_sign_up()

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    @data(*get_csv_data('/Users/blabla/utilities/test_data.csv'))
    @unpack
    def test_invalid_sign_up_invalid_email(self, invalid_email):
        self.test_user.invalid_signup(invalid_email)
        time.sleep(3)
        result = self.test_user.verify_error_sign_up()
```

What could happen? I've double checked the file test_data.csv for extra spaces, etc.

```
invalid_email
qqq
111
```

Error message:

```
fixture 'invalid_email' not found
available fixtures: base_set_up, browser...
use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

Comment: I think you need  to supply more code (minmal reproducible example) and post the complete error message

Comment: I've added more code and the error message.

Comment: So this is exactely what the error message tells you, that it cannot find the `@pytest.fixture` `invalid_email`, maybe search your code for this function.

Comment: I've thought it's supposed to read a csv file and then unpack the data from it to use in test_invalid_sign_up_invalid_email function...

Comment: I don't know ... Did you search your code for it? Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

If you click on the decorator, it says:

```
def data(*values):
    """
    Method decorator to add to your test methods.

    Should be added to methods of instances of ``unittest.TestCase``.

    """
    return idata(values)
```

So you have to import unittest first, and then do this:

```
class TestSignUp(unittest.TestCase)
```